# Can $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be expressed as the union of disjoint positive measure sets with cardinal $\aleph_1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As the title suggested, can we find positive measure sets$\{V_j\}_{j\in\alpha}$, such that $$V_j\cap V_k=\emptyset, \quad \cup_{j\in\alpha}{V_j=\mathbb{R}^{n}},$$
and the cardinal number of this set is $\aleph_1$.

Comment: Which cardinal do you mean? $\aleph_0$?

Comment: $$\mathbb{R}^n=\cup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\big[ [i,i+1[\times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}\big]$$

Comment: Sorry, I mean $\aleph_1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the disjoint union of subsets of positive measure, there are at most $\aleph_0$ of these subsets.

Suppose that there are an infinite number, as otherwise the proposition is evident.  Partitioning any subsets of infinite measure into ones of finite measure can then be done without increasing the (infinite) cardinality of these subsets, as infinite measured portions are subdivided into countably many pieces, e.g. intersections with half-open hypercubes $\Pi[k_i,k_i+1)$.

Now count for each $1/r$, $r = 1,2,\ldots$, how many such subsets have measure at least $1/r$.  There are at most countably many.  Summing the count (including repetitions) as $r \rightarrow \infty$ shows that there are at most countably many of positive measure.

I think I remember an exercise like this in Rudin.

Comment: How do you know that "There are at most countably many"?

Comment: Using the subdivision into unit hypercube intersections, there will be at most $r$ subsets of size at least $1/r$ in each unit hypercube.  Thus there can be at most countably many pieces spread across the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Oh I see now. I would have replaced Lebesgue measure by an equivalent finite measure (say, Gaussian) from the start. But that's just me:)

Comment: My phrasing was overly terse; I was on the move.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** This answer is now obsolete following an edit to the question; but hardmath has posted a very nice solution to the intended question.

---

By $\aleph$ do you mean $\aleph_0$? If so then yes: for instance, define
$$V_k = [k,k+1) \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$$
Then $\mathbb{R}^n = \displaystyle \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} V_k$ and $V_k \cap V_{\ell} = \varnothing$ for $k \ne \ell$. (Imagine chopping $\mathbb{R}^n$ into layers.)

In fact you can express $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a disjoint union of countably many sets of positive *finite* measure using intuition along similar lines: take unit $n$-cubes instead of layers.

Comment: And the relevant search term here for the OP is [$\sigma$-finite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-finite_measure).

Comment: I mean $\aleph_1$,and I think this will make it harder to solve.